# Does SQL Merge Statement trigger multiple Targets if they match?

Tags: sql-server

I came across an merge statement in the Database at work today and looked into it.

I learned that it is an easy way to check if an entry is in the target or the source table or if it is in both.

And if I use `when matched and ...` I can check it on different columns of the tables.

But if I now have multiple of these conditions do they then all triger together?

For example if I merge two Person tables how would the following code behave?

```
MERGE SourcePersons AS sp
USING TargetPerson AS tp
ON (sp.Id = tp.Id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (Id, Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (sp.Id, sp.Firstname, sp.Lastname)
WHEN MATCHED AND (sp.Firstname <> tp.Firstname)
THEN UPDATE SET Firstname = sp.Firstname
WHEN MATCHED AND (sp.Lastname <> tp.Lastname)
THEN UPDATE SET Lastname = sp.Lastname
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
/*No idea what to write here*/
;
```

In the above I have two updates for the firstname and lastname respectively, if now a person changes both names do both of them trigger or does only firstname trigger as that is the first one?

Comment: You can have only a single `WHEN MATCHED` section

Comment: If you have 2 `WHEN MATCHED`, the first must be `WHEN MATCHED AND` and the second without the `AND`. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#when-matched-then-merge_matched)

Comment: Each `WHEN` is only triggered once per row, whichever matches first

Comment: @DanGuzman The documentation only says that the first must have an `AND` it doesn't state that the second one has to be without the `AND`. Both can have further conditions applied [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cb259378db58c25bd4d49a5afc7d1ef)

Comment: Obligatory: https://sqlblog.org/merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both Firstname and Lastname update when Matched and ignore `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`

```
MERGE SourcePersons AS sp
USING TargetPerson AS tp ON (sp.Id = tp.Id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (Id, Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (sp.Id, sp.Firstname, sp.Lastname)
WHEN MATCHED AND ((sp.Firstname <> tp.Firstname) OR (sp.Lastname <> tp.Lastname))
THEN UPDATE SET Firstname = sp.Firstname, Lastname = sp.Lastname ;
```

OR

You can have both the WHEN MATCHED clauses. According to Document, we can have two WHEN MATCHED clauses [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#when-matched-then-merge_matched)

```
MERGE SourcePersons AS sp
USING TargetPerson AS tp ON (sp.Id = tp.Id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT (Id, Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (sp.Id, sp.Firstname, sp.Lastname)
WHEN MATCHED AND (sp.Firstname <> tp.Firstname)
THEN UPDATE SET Firstname = sp.Firstname
WHEN MATCHED AND (sp.Lastname <> tp.Lastname)
THEN UPDATE SET Lastname = sp.Lastname ;
```

Comment: You can't have two `WHEN MATCHED` clauses with both having `THEN UPDATE`

Comment: Got it. If two `WHEN MATCHED` clauses specified, one is for `UPDATE` and other is for `DELETE`.

Comment: The idea was to have them both individual to either update the Firstname or the Lastname or both if both change, but not both if just one of them changed.
If it is not possible to do it with two seperate `WHEN MATCHED AND...` clauses then I guess I have to use `iif` in these cases to control more precisely what gets changed.

Comment: @SoulB Why? If you're updating the row, just update both columns (even if one of them didn't actually change). The cost of the write, the impact to the log, etc. is essentially the same. Treating it otherwise seems to be premature optimization. See [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/conditional-updates) for some tangential details.